# Kotlin Fuel download takes long time to connect

Tags: kotlin-fuel

Using Fuel 2.0.1 in Android Studio with Kotlin 1.3.31.

My Fuel download request looks as follows

```
Log.i("tag","connecting")
Fuel.download(uri).fileDestination { response, url ->
    File(filesDir,filename)
}.progress { readBytes, totalBytes ->
    Log.i("tag","downloading")
}.response { req, res, result ->
    Log.i("tag","download complete")
}
```

There is about 5-7 seconds delay between the connecting and downloading logs.
I tried putting the url into the browser on the same device and it starts downloading instantly.
I also tried other servers but the lag is the same.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Did you solve this issue? I am experiencing the same and have stopped using Fuel because of this. Instead of using Fuel to download a file I'm doing it this way:

```
val url = "https://www.abcde.com/fghij/filename.apk"
val filename = "filename.apk"
URL(url + filename).openStream().use { input ->
    FileOutputStream(File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), filename)).use { output ->
        input.copyTo(output)
    }
}
```

Comment: No, I haven't. Is there a way to get download progress percent with your solution?

Comment: In my case I didn't need the download progress percent so I don't know if it is possible.